# AWS Lex Error "Error: Something went wrong, please try again, if your problem persists then please contact the bot's developer. "

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lex

I saw the same error as one mentioned in this post [aws forum post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=813898&tstart=0)

`Error: Something went wrong, please try again, if your problem persists then please contact the bot's developer. Error occurred at: 2019-10-09T15:58:29.153Z[UTC].`

The messenger I was using with Lex integration was working the previous week and nothing new was added to the code base. Does anyone know if there is a recent change to Lex that could cause this?

Comment: no exceptions in cloudwatch of any sort? (check the validation and fulfilment lambdas)

Comment: @HoratiuJeflea no exceptions in cloudwatch of any sort were found. For reasons that still can not be explained, the Lex integration is working again the next morning with no code changes of any kind from my end.